# Objective c - UITableView - Cell Not removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to Delete row of custom cell , I have managed to delete the item from his class, but everytime that I remove the last row in the tableView (when i have only one for example), the cell is reset but not remove and i still see her in the view.
btw - reloadData not working for me.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell = (TableCell*)selectedCell;

    // Delete the row from the data source.
    [User DeleteUserFromList:cell.Id];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [User GetUserList].count;
}
```

Comment: did you check the cell object and made sure it is correct

Comment: What's the thing with `TableCell *cell` and then `cell = (TableCell *)selectedCell;` I can't why you do that. Did you check the dataSource array after the delete?

Comment: Looks ok so far. Are you positive that `[User GetUserList].count` really evaluates to `0`? BTW, although not related to your problem, `GetUserList` and `DeletUserFromList:` are methods and should be named `getUserList` and deleteUeserFromList:` . Can you share the code of both, especially of `deleteUserFromList`?